# Where are close votes?

Tags: discussion, support

Where are close votes located on questions and answers? I don't see the number of voters anywhere, on any question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voting to close/put on hold is only available for questions. Once you have enough reputation to vote for close, there is a „close“ link beneath the question (similar to „edit“ and „flag“). This is shown as „close(1)“ when there is already a pending vote.

Comment: Yes, this is mentionned in the help center. But I saw that it was possible to "see close votes" from 250 rep. And I don't see the close button, because it is obviously not available for me. I was just looking for this in order to check whether my question or answer should be improved, so I can do it in time before it gets closed.

Comment: You should see it under your own questions. https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes